# JQuery DatePicker constrainInput: true not working like I think it should

Tags: jquery

It is only allowing numbers in the box  if you type "22" you cannot type a space or any characthers.

How do I fix this

```
<SCRIPT>
    $(function() {
        $( "#dateExpire" ).datepicker({ 
        constrainInput: true,
        changeYear:true, 
        altField: 'input#dateExpire', 
        altFormat: 'dd M yy',
        minDate: new Date(2011, 8,9</cfoutput>)
        });
    });
</SCRIPT>
```

Comment: I was copying someone elses code and realised the alt field was the issue.  I changed it to dateformat like you said and it works fine. I did not need altField or altFormat for what I was trying to do. Also for anyone reading this you do not need to use the constrainInput unless you are wanting to change form the default value true to be false.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You fix it by applying the format you want to the dateFormat option:

```
dateFormat: 'dd M yy'
```

constrainInput: http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#option-constrainInput

> When true entry in the input field is constrained to those characters allowed by the current dateFormat.

dateFormat: http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#option-dateFormat

Answer (score 0):

Another solutions is you don't use 'constrainInput' at all.

What you can is bind an 'keyup' event listener on the date_picker field and set the value

to empty. i.e. date_picker field would have a valid value if it is selected from the date

picker otherwise it would remain empty.

```
$("#date_picker_id")

.datepicker()

.on('keyup', function () {

                $(this).val('');

            });
```